# How to merge xml files using xslt and remove empty elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, merge

I have several files that I want to merge, ignoring empty elements.

For example :
File 1:

```
    <ds>
    <sk>
    <f1>1</f1>
    <f2>2</f2>
    </sk>
    <sk>
    <f1>3</f1>
    <f2>4</f2>
    </sk>
    </ds>
```

file 2 :

```
    <ds>
    <ac>
    <g1>9</f1>
    <g2>10</f2>
    </ac>
    <ac>
    <g1>11</f1>
    <g2>12</f2>
    </ac>
    </ds>
```

and File 3:

```
    <ds>
    <rs>
    <k1>A</f1>
    <k2>B</f2>
    <k3></k3>
    </rs>
    <rs>
    <k1>C</f1>
    <k2>B</f2>
    <k3/>
    </rs>
    </ds>
```

I want as outpout:

```
    <ds>
    <sk>
    <f1>1</f1>
    <f2>2</f2>
    </sk>
    <sk>
    <f1>3</f1>
    <f2>4</f2>
    </sk>
    <ac>
    <g1>9</f1>
    <g2>10</f2>
    </ac>
    <ac>
    <g1>11</f1>
    <g2>12</f2>
    </ac>
    <rs>
    <k1>A</f1>
    <k2>B</f2>
    </rs>
    <rs>
    <k1>C</f1>
    <k2>B</f2>
    </rs>
    </ds>
```

I have tried this as xslt :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <xsl:transform
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xml:space="preserve"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="/ds">
         <xsl:copy-of select="document('File1')/ds/sk"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="document('File2')/ds/ac"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="document('File3')/ds/rs"/>
     </xsl:template>

    </xsl:transform>
```

Input is File1. Files are merge but I cannot figure how to remove empty elements like  or  in File3.
Any idea ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, I cannot really see what you are doing: Your xslt is incomplete, the `xsl:for-each` have no body and are not closed. I assume your code is doing whatever you mean exactly by “merging”?

Comment: there was a mistake, it is not for-each but copy-of.

Comment: Thanks, but you should still close them to get legal XML. (It's usually a good idea to copy&paste tested code.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your XML file were actually well-formed, you should start off by using the XSLT identity transform

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, instead of doing `xsl:for-each`, do `xsl:apply-templates` instead.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('File1')/ds/sk" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('File2')/ds/ac" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('File3')/ds/rs" />
```

Note, you may not necessarily need to use the `document` function on `File1` if that happens to be the input file of the XSLT itself.

Then to remove empty elements, just add a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="document('File1')/ds/sk" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="document('File2')/ds/ac" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="document('File3')/ds/rs" />
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]" />
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thks, I have tried the given xslt, but no xml is outputted at all. note : there was a mistake in my initial post, I was using copy-of instead of for-each ... and i'm using msxml to transform.

Comment: Feel free to amend your initial post to correct your mistake. Also, I've made a small edit to my answer. You do need to make sure the `document` function references the correct file path for each file. If you enter just `File1.xml` it will (probably) look for the XML in the same folder as the XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: File1.xml is located in the same directory, but I use absolut path anyway. I was using c:\test\File1.xml, tried with file:///c:/test/File1.xml, the result is the same, no output file...

Comment: Does my answer produce an output if replace `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of`?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure why but the problem is solved using this xslt

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="document('File1')/ds/sk" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="document('File2')/ds/ac" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="document('File3')/ds/rs" />
     </xls:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]" />
```

Note : yours was performing well using Altova (with msxml as parser). In my code (powerbuilder), i need to use this one ...

Comment: What's the difference to Tim's answer?